# How to make accessible multiple custom textfield in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

Below is my code, As given in code If my table has more than one row than I can't access that text field means I can type text but my keyboard doesn't disappear and if I have only one row than it is accessible, Can anyone help me how to make more than one textfield accessible because I want to create it as dynamically not by fix code

```
textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 21, 21)];
textField1.placeholder = @"0";

textField1.delegate = self;
textField1.text = [numberofevent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.accessoryView = textField1 ;
[self textFieldShouldReturn:textField1];
[textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
[textField1 release];
```

And this one is for resign keyboard code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}
```

and last one is for my text value changed event

```
- (void) textChanged:(UITextField *)source {
}
```

So, this code run for any number of row, but it can't give access when row is more than one so how can I generate multiple textfield within one code as per app needed and how can i access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue involving `textField1`. First of all, it is apparently an instance variable because you are accessing it from at least two methods, but you release it at the end of what I presume is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (your first block of code here) and after that point really shouldn't be referring to `textField1` any more (even though it is retained by the cell). So I don't think `textField1` should be an ivar at all. The second problem is that you are always referring to `textField1` in `textFieldShouldReturn:` rather than `textField`. Who knows what `textField1` will refer to by the time `textFieldShouldReturn:` is called, but `textField` will always refer to whatever text field should be returning.

In short, I think you need to change this:

`[textField1 resignFirstResponder];`

to this:

`[textField resignFirstResponder];`

I'm also not sure why you are calling textFieldShouldReturn yourself from within cellForRowAtIndexPath. There is also another UITextFieldDelegate method that you should probably be using rather than adding your own action/target to the text fields.

This might fix your main problem, unless there are other issues in the rest of your code.

EDIT: Let me try to explain this even more clearly. You have one text field per row. By the time all of your cells are created in cellForRowAtIndexPath, `textField1` refers **only** to the very last text field that was created. Your `textFieldShouldReturn` method **always** refers to `textField1`. It should refer to its argument, `textField`, which corresponds to the actual text field that was first responder when the return was initiated.

Comment: No Adam, It's not like that either i pass                   [textField1 resignFirstResponder]; or                                   [textField1 resignFirstResponder]; both are same because I have declare textfield1 as textfield. You have not get my point, this run and access only for one row but when I run for multiple rows it shows me textfield and also I can type in that textfield but my keyboard doesn't hide when row is more than one. Do you get it or not. If you have any idea than suggest me where is problem

Comment: What method is that first block of code you posted coming from? Do you have a text field in each row? I'm also confused about why you are calling a UITextFieldDelegate method yourself (textFieldShouldReturn).

Comment: Ya I have textfield in each row and I want to dismiss my keyboard when return key pressed at each row but this doesn't happens with multiple row it only happens when row is only one.

Comment: What method is that first block of code you posted from? I'm still pretty sure that my original answer is correct.

Comment: Hey Brother I am also an experienced developer in iOS, And I have tested code in multiple ways and I have tried your suggestion also but it didn't respond. Ok I give you sample code, copy and paste it in your table view and run it by once giving one row and than multiple row and you will get my point.

Comment: As I have given in question type that code in your tableview class and you will get idea what error exactly occur

Comment: I think there is only one solution if I can create multiple textfield like this way UITextField *textfield-i = [[UITextField alloc]init]; where -i = indexpath.row, but unluckily there is no method like this in iOS, if you have any idea if we can create textfield like this than it would be possible.

Comment: Can you please answer my question? I am asking you what method is that first block of code, the one that creates textField1, found in your code. Is it in cellForRowAtIndexPath? I can't tell how your code is working unless I know what methods the code is from.

Comment: Ya its below method from where first block of code comes                                                                      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I figured. My original answer still addresses your main problem. I added some explanation to my answer that might help you understand. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a good code, but should get you up and running. Reuse the view and stuff on your code, set up the textfield properly etc. Basically what's wrong with yours at the moment is you're using 1 textfield for every cell.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell   = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 21, 21)];
            textField.placeholder = @"0";
            textField.delegate = self;
            textField.text = [numberofevent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.accessoryView = textField;
        }
        // do something else here if the cell is reused
    }
```